# gradle - checkstyle config file in separate jar

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to force checkstyle plugin to use xml configuration stored in different jar file (as a dependency).

I've created a package that contains just that config file.

In build.gradle I have the following config:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

checkstyle {
    checkstyleMain {
        classpath += configurations.checkstyleDep
    }
    checkstyleTest {
        classpath += configurations.checkstyleDep
    }
    configFile = new File(getClass().getResource("/checkstyle.xml").toURI())
    println(configFile)
}

configurations {
    checkstyleDep
}

dependencies {
    checkstyleDep "com.example:checkstyle-common:1.0"
}
```

Unfortunately this does not cause gradle to see the dependency.

What are problems with my code? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is the the 'com.example:checkstyle-common:1.0' jar available in your repository?

Comment: Yes, it is - I've put it into local maven repo and it is downloaded properly.

Comment: did you try adding it as a buildscript dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this approach (Gradle 5.0):

```
# add the checkstyle plugin
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "checkstyle"
}

# load the dependency that has the rules
configurations {
    checkstyleRules
}

dependencies {
    checkstyleRules "com.github.ngeor:checkstyle-rules:3.3.0"
}

# configure checkstyle
checkstyle {
    toolVersion "8.24"
    config project.resources.text.fromArchiveEntry(configurations.checkstyleRules, "com/github/ngeor/checkstyle.xml")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since gradle 2.2 you can set the config xml as a string.

I did

```
checkstyle {
    config = getClass().getResource("checkstyle.xml").text
}
```