How to configure Checkstyle config from a JAR dependency in Gradle
I seem to have stumbled upon a very simple problem (which should be very straight-forward) but unable to find an answer for the last 4 hrs.
I am trying to configure a custom checkstyle config in my gradle project from a dependency (JAR) that has been imported into my project. The dependency is successfully pulled from our internal nexus maven repo (I can see the files under External libraries in IntelliJ).
Here's my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repository..../repository/maven-releases')
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("tech.qa:UICheckstyle:1.0.8")
}


I have ensured the checkstyle is available under config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml (the default location) inside UIcheckstyle repo.
Here is everything I have tried:

When I run gradle build for the above setup, I get the following error:

Execution failed for task ':checkstyleMain'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.CheckstyleAction
   > An unexpected error occurred configuring and executing Checkstyle.
      > Unable to create Root Module: config {/Users/arjunvijayakumar/Desktop/workspaces/ui-automation/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml}, classpath {null}.


Update the dependencies to:

dependencies {
    checkstyle("tech.qa:UICheckstyle:1.0.8")
}

The error is:
Execution failed for task ':checkstyleMain'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.CheckstyleAction
   > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask


Added checkstyle block:

checkstyle {
    configFile = rootProject.file("config/configuration/checkstyle.xml")
    // This is obviously wrong. I am not sure how to access the file inside the JAR
}

Do I have to go down this path to access the file through ClassLoader. Sounds very primitive and I feel there has to be a much simpler way.
Kindly let me know if anyone can help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

This answer to use custom configuration saved my day - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58644302/5292948

Package the configuration file as a Zip archive and publish it to your organization’s Maven or Ivy repository. For the following example, we are going to assume that the archive has been published to https://mavenrepo.mycompany.com with identifier mycompany.com:checkstyle-config:1.0.
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "checkstyle"

repositories {
   maven {
     url "https://mavenrepo.mycompany.com"
   }
 }

 configurations {
    checkstyleConfig
 }

 dependencies {
    checkstyleConfig "mycompany.com:checkstyle-config:+@zip"
 }

 checkstyle {
     config = resources.text.fromArchiveEntry(
       configurations.checkstyleConfig, "checkstyle-config.xml")
 }

http://web.archive.org/web/20150322034610/http://www.gradleware.com/tutorials/feature-spotlight-enforcing-code-quality-standards/

The only way I found to load the checkstyle configuration from inside a jar was to create a custom utility class that loads it from the resources directory.
This approach comes from this repository I found while searching a solution for troubleshooting this issue: https://github.com/Lucas3oo/solrike-conventions-gradle-plugin/tree/main/src/main/groovy/se/solrike/conventions/utils
Here's the code I have adapted for kotlin DSL:
package com.example.gradle.utils

import org.gradle.api.Project
import java.io.File
import java.net.URI
import java.net.URL

object ResourceLoader {

    fun getResourceAsFile(project: Project, name: String): File {
        val file = project.file(project.resources.text.fromUri(getResourceAsUri(name)))
        // change file type ending from the generated .txt to what the resource has
        val fileType = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.'))
        val newFileName = file.absolutePath + fileType
        val newFile = project.file(newFileName)
        file.copyTo(newFile)
        return newFile
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * @return e.g. jar:file:/some-path/my-jar.jar!/path-inside-jar/the-file.xml
     */
    fun getResourceAsUri(name: String): URI {
        return getResourceAsUrl(name)?.toURI() ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Resource not found: $name")
    }

    private fun getResourceAsUrl(name: String): URL? {
        return ResourceLoader.javaClass.getResource(name)
    }

}

import com.example.gradle.utils.ResourceLoader

plugins {
    idea
    java
    checkstyle
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "10.17.0"
    val checkstylePath = "/plugin-config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml"
    configFile = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsFile(project, checkstylePath)
}

tasks.withType<Checkstyle>().configureEach {
    maxHeapSize = "1g"
    reports {
        xml.required = false
        html.required = true
    }
}

I wrapped the logic into a convention plugin which follows the following directory structure:
java-conventions/
├─ src/
│  ├─ main/
│  │  ├─ kotlin/
│  │  │  ├─ com/
│  │  │  │  ├─ example/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ gradle/
│  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ utils/
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ ResourceLoader.kts
│  │  │  ├─ com.example.java-conventions.gradle.kts
│  │  ├─ resources/
│  │  │  ├─ plugin-config/
│  │  │  │  ├─ checkstyle/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ checkstyle.xml
├─ build.gradle.kts

After publishing it to maven local I can use it in my projects by declaring it in the plugins block as follows:
plugins {
    id("com.example.java-conventions") version "1.0.0"
}

